# How to forward web-socket request to microservice using nginx

Tags: nginx, websocket, socket.io, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy

I wanted to forward the web-socket request to microservice using nginx.

I am hitting `https://some-host/download-zip-service/downloadFile`

By this, the calls are landing on **download-zip-service** and **downloadFile** API get the call.

in **downloadFile** I am using the socket to forward the request to microservice

but when I tried to call socket API from **download-zip-service** 
I do something like `var socket = io('https://some-host/download-zip-service/');`

the calls are directly landing on
`wss://some-host/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=12345678`

instead of `https://some-host/download-zip-service/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=12345678`

as a reason, I explicitly added the root `/` path for download-zip-service.

Below is my NGINX.conf file

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    sendfile on;

    upstream download-zip-service {
        server xx.xx.xx.xx:9012;

    }


server {
        listen 8765;
        #Changed for implementing WEB Socket
        location / {
            proxy_pass         http://download-zip-service/;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            # proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            # proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            # proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            # proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            #new property added
            proxy_request_buffering off;
            proxy_buffering off;
        }

        location /download-zip-service/ {
            proxy_pass         http://download-zip-service/;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            # proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            # proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            # proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            # proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            #socket timeout setting added
            fastcgi_read_timeout 7200s; 
            send_timeout 7200s;
            proxy_connect_timeout 7200s;
            proxy_send_timeout 7200s;
            proxy_read_timeout 7200s;
            #new property added
            proxy_request_buffering off;
            proxy_buffering off; 
        }

    }

}
```

I want to remove the root `/` path for download-zip-service.
and it should work with `/download-zip-service/`
Please let me know where I am doing mistake